# JSONDecoder not loading text from api

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I want to get the `home_name` of the first team. But it shows me blank.
This is my JSON fetching Code:

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    static var test = ""
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/teams/matches.json?number=10&team_id=19&key=##KEY##&secret=##SECRET##&number=7&team_id=46") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = gettingInfo {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.posts = results.data
                                NetworkManager.test = results.data[0].home_name
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

My struct:

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Decodable {
    let data: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return objectID
    }
    let objectID: String
    let home_name: String
    let away_name: String
}
```

And my view but the view shouldn't be the problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(NetworkManager.test)
            .onAppear {
                self.networkManager.fetchData()
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what `results` contains?

Comment: `test` isn't marked as `Published`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@Published var test = ""`

Comment: I tried to edit your post to hide the actual `api_key` and `secret`. That's very bad to share it online for everyone to grab!!

Comment: Thanks guys it works now. Published was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
struct Results: Decodable {
    let data: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var objectID: String {
        return id
    }
    let home_name: String
    let away_name: String
}

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    @Published var test = ""
    
    func fetchData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/teams/matches.json?number=10&team_id=19&keykey_here&secret=secret_here&number=7&team_id=46") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = gettingInfo {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.posts = results.data
                                self.test = results.data[0].home_name
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(networkManager.test)
            .onAppear {
                self.networkManager.fetchData()
            }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

You have made two mistakes

1. marked `test` as static instead of marking it as @Published
2. `Post` - here you are returning id from objectId instead you should have id from the JSON and you have to return objectID from id value.

Comment: @saurabh Prajapati hide the OP's `shared key` and `secret` from the request. Most probably he is new into programming and doesn't know the security issues with sharing his paid key.

Comment: I try to use this now with my widget. But it stays blank. Any Idea? Is the Widget with WidgetKit working different?